# Paypal recurring payment in Payflow sandbox account

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, payflowpro

Can it be possible to work with recurring payment in Paypal Payflow sandbox account,
If yes can anyone please explain the process or provided reference links

Comment: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECRecurringPayments/

Comment: You can readout from here in details.